# Cannot restart Docker container due to input/output error?

Tags: docker, tcp, dns, ioerror

I noticed my `Redis` instance on my local pc stopped working. I use `Docker` to host it and tried to issue a `restart` command on the container as `ps` stated it was running*.

```
docker restart my-redis
```

However this yielded the following error message:

> Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container my-redis: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint my-redis (...): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:32777:tcp:172.17.0.2:6379: input/output error

*I've been running a DNS server on the same machine where I run `Docker`. There is a service started when my PC boots which also listens at port 53. I need to shut down this process in order for my DNS server to boot up properly. I suspect this is a process used by `Docker` and as a result it might be able to start up the container initially, but fails when issued a `restart` (because of that process being shut down).

I already set up Docker to use my local DNS server (under Settings -> Network in `Docker for Windows`), but I'm not really sure if this is at all related to the `input/output` error that breaks my container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to have happened for many(usually on `Windows`) and not solved clearly. Refer this [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/573).

However, there would be a temporary method to solve it, which is disabling `experimental features`(in the above issue, many are saying it is solved after disabling `experimental features`).

I am not sure how to disable it and which `OS` you are using but you could easily google to find how to disable it for the `OS`.

Comment: Ok disabling `experimental features` solved it for me thank you. It was located in the Docker for Windows `Deamon` settings screen as a checkbox.

Comment: Funny. For me it worked when I ENABLE experimental features...^^ (neo4j image)

Comment: @SteveRakebrandt after restart i had the same issue (after enabling it the first time) then i disabled it and it worked 
i believe its not related to what `experimental features` is i think just changing it triggers something that solve the problem :p

Comment: Disable and enable experimental features will cause docker restart, so the real solution is to restart the docker.

Answer (score 2):

Um been happening for me also - was about to write a post.  I had created a weblogic container yesterday and stopped started it several times in day ok ( no overnight reboot)

cam to try and start today and got this error on my windows 10 main machine

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint wls (dd11b7bd7d23df50651a94eec68cdd2ec59e160d9c4ae8caa682f0a037218393): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:9002:tcp:172.17.0.2:9002: input/output error
```

where the docker ports is showing tcp:172.17.0.2

This has happended before after overnight shut down and restart on fresh day on my windows desktop, even though docker said it was running ok

I ignored that and just told it to restart, and tried the docker start again and it worked

when you do a docker ps -all now it shows

`ports: 0.0.0.0:7001->7001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9002->9002/tcp` which indicates its working again

so something spooky going on under the covers in network mappings - weird

13/03/2019

Comment: I also had this issue and What did works for me is restarting the machine and docker as @WILLIAM WOODMAN told.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was that Docker was killed while the redis was in a process of making a disk dump.

I solved the problem by deleting temp-1.rdb temp-2.rdb files.

dump.rdb file is your latest stable backup, do NOT delete that one.

Answer (score 0):

I met this err cause there is an disk err.

`dmesg`  show sdi err

and my container start will create volume in that broken sdi disk (read only err)

fix disk err works for me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbJvY.jpg)

Comment: Please do not use images of text rendered: include the text. Please follow prompts such as *enter image description here*.